# NoMethodError: undefined method `within' for main:Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, capistrano3, rake-task

I'm trying to make Capistrano deploy script.

In my Capfile I make sure all rake tasks are included

```
# Load tasks
Dir.glob('config/capistrano_tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

Next I have a 'migrations.rake' containing:

```
namespace :fileservice do
    task :migrate do
        within release_path do
            info 'Doing migrations'

            execute :php, fetch(:symfony_console_path), 'doctrine:migrations:migrate', '--no-interaction', fetch(:symfony_console_flags)
        end
    end
end
```

In my deploy.rb I call the task at the very end with:

```
after 'deploy:publishing', 'fileservice:migrate'
```

For some reason I keep getting an error saying:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `within' for main:Object
```

I have no idea where to look or what might be wrong... When googling I get a lot of "NoMethodError" hits but none about the 'within' method and most are general Ruby errors.

Where should "within" be defined? I dat a ruby on rails thing? Or capistrano?

Hopefully someone knows where to start looking or which library / script to include!

**UPDATE:** I just discovered that none of the methods work. When removing lines I got the same error for "info" and "execute".... So I guess somewhere, something is missing.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell Capistrano *where* (i.e. on what servers) to run your SSH commands. Do this using an `on` block, as follows:

```
namespace :fileservice do
  task :migrate do
    on roles(:db) do
      within release_path do
        info 'Doing migrations'
        execute :php, fetch(:symfony_console_path), 'doctrine:migrations:migrate', '--no-interaction', fetch(:symfony_console_flags)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Replace `roles(:db)` as appropriate for your task, depending on where you want the commands to be run. The expression `on roles(:all) do ... end`, for example, will run the commands on all servers.

---

You can also follow the official documentation at http://capistranorb.com, or the [Capistrano README](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/README.md), both of which show examples of the `task`/`on`/`execute` syntax.

Comment: That was indeed the problem. I had removed that since at this moment there is only one server. Had nog idea it was actually mandatory! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

As you already got the answer but Let me put the bulb from basic.

[SSHKit](https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit) was actually developed and released with Capistrano 3, and it’s basically a lower-level tool that provides methods for connecting and interacting with remote servers; it does all the heavy lifting for Capistrano, in other words.

**There are four main methods you need to know about.**

**`on()`**: specifies the server to run on

**`within()`**: specifies the directory path to run in

**`as()`**: specifies the user to run as

**`with()`**: specifies the environment variables to run with

Typically, you’ll start a task by using an `on()` method to specify the server on which you want your commands to run. Then you can use any combination of `as()`, `within()`, and `with()` methods, which are repeatable and stackable in any order.

Hope this help you